# Orientation change issue in Highcharts after navigating to an inner component | Winter '18 release

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, winter18, ipad, highcharts

I am facing an issue in iPad where the Highcharts width and height are not being reset after navigating to an inner component and changing the screen orientation and coming back.

Here's the code:-

Highchart's component:-

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <ltng:require scripts="{!join(',', 
                $Resource.l_staticresource + '/scripts/jQuery_V1.js', 
                $Resource.l_staticresource + '/scripts/highcharts.src.js',
                $Resource.l_staticresource + '/scripts/exporting.src.js',
                $Resource.l_staticresource + '/scripts/offline-exporting.src.js'
                    )}"
                  afterScriptsLoaded="{!c.afterLoad}" />


    <aura:attribute name="isResourcesLoaded" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>


    <div aura:id="containerChart" id="container" style="height:600px; width: 90%; margin: 0 auto;">    
    </div>
</aura:component>
```

Controller:-

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        helper.drawChart(component, helper);       
    },
    afterLoad : function(component, event, helper) {
        if(component.isValid()) {
            component.set("v.isResourcesLoaded", true);
        }
    }
})
```

Helper:-

```
({
    drawChart : function(component, helper) {
        if(component.isValid() && component.get("v.isResourcesLoaded")) {
            Highcharts.chart('container', {
                chart: {
                    type: 'column'
                },
                title: {
                    text: 'Stacked column chart'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    categories: ['Apples', 'Oranges', 'Pears', 'Grapes', 'Bananas']
                },
                yAxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    title: {
                        text: 'Total fruit consumption'
                    },
                    stackLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        style: {
                            fontWeight: 'bold',
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                        }
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    align: 'right',
                    x: -30,
                    verticalAlign: 'top',
                    y: 25,
                    floating: true,
                    backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.background2) || 'white',
                    borderColor: '#CCC',
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    shadow: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    headerFormat: '<b>{point.x}</b><br/>',
                    pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.y}<br/>Total: {point.stackTotal}'
                },
                plotOptions: {
                    column: {
                        stacking: 'normal',
                        dataLabels: {
                            enabled: true,
                            color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white'
                        }
                    },
                    series: {
                                animation: false,
                                cursor: 'pointer',                                      
                                point: {
                                    events: {
                                        click: function () {
                                                helper.navigateToReport(component);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                },
                series: [{
                    name: 'John',
                    data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
                }, {
                    name: 'Jane',
                    data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
                }, {
                    name: 'Joe',
                    data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
                }]
            });
        }
    },
    navigateToReport: function(component) {
        var navigateToDrilldownEvent = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");

        navigateToDrilldownEvent.setParams({
            componentDef: "c:HighchartsDemoDrillDown"            
        });
        navigateToDrilldownEvent.fire();
    }
})
```

Renderer:-

```
({
    afterRender: function(component, helper) {
        this.superAfterRender();
    },
    rerender: function(component, helper) {
        this.superRerender();   
        helper.drawChart(component, helper);
    }
})
```

HighchartsDemoDrillDown(Inner component) component:-

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global" >
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-1 errorText">
        Now, when you change the orientation from here and click the back button, the Highchart's width and height does not change.
    </div>
    <div class="slds-size_1-of-1 errorText">
        This issue was not present prior to Salesforce Winter '18 release.
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

Steps to reproduce the issue:-

After clicking the chart, you are navigated to an inner component. From the inner component, when you change the screen's orientation and click the back button, the Highchart's width and height does not change. This issue was not present prior to Salesforce Winter '18 release.

**I have created an unmanaged package to replicate the issue so that it would be easier to debug.**

**Here's the installation URL:-     https://login.salesforce.com/packaging/installPackage.apexp?p0=04t0I000000qq09**
(Please do not forget to add "HighchartsDemo" tab in Salesforce Navigation.)

Is there any workaround to fix this?

Comment: Hi @PawelFus Do you have any insights on this behaviour?

Comment: It doesn't looke like a Highcharts issue - if this was fine in previous Salesforce versions, then... Let's debug this a little (I don't have Salesforce account): Could you add `chart.events.redraw` and check if this callback is fired? Additionally, could you check width&height of the container when `redraw` is called? Note: You have fixed height, so it shouldn't change.

Comment: Hi @PawełFus Thanks for replying. I'm sorry, `redraw` is getting fired when orientation is changed from the Highcharts screen. But when navigated to inner component and orientation is changed and coming back, then the `redraw` is not being fired.

Comment: In portrait mode, initially the height is 600px and width is 692px. When orientation is changed from the first screen itself, when redraw function is triggered, it's height and width are same. And after the alert from `redraw` function when it's in landscape mode height is 600px and width is 922px. (I have hardcoded height value in pixels in parent div).

Comment: Thank you for the details. That info with `redraw` not being called is important - this means chart can't be re-rendered. Does salesforce provide any event when orientation changed? We could call there `chart.reflow()` or `chart.setSize(width, height)`. I'm asking for this event, because I assume `window resize` doesn't work..

Comment: No, Salesforce doesn't provide with any such event, but the thing is when I tried by using the `resize` function written inside the chart component itself and it fires and when navigated to the inner component when orientation is changed(But the thing is I think we won't get the `chart` thing from inside the inner component.. I had tried giving `redraw` inside the resize function..(But it's not actually redrawing that, eventhough it's being fired..) ).. And, I will try to use `chart.reflow()` inside the function and let you know.. Thank you very much for the follow up, @PawełFus :) .